# Determine what property a collection belongs to

Tags: c#, observablecollection, .net-4.8

I've created a little test. How can I find out, perhaps using reflection when inside void Add(T t) what property does the collection belong to? I want to programmatically get the property name 'MyVotes' possibly via a PropertyInfo.

```
void Main()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.MyVotes.Add("Democratic");
    myClass.MyVotes.Add("Republican");
    myClass.MyVotes.Add("Independent");
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyCollection<string> MyVotes { get; }
    
    public MyClass()
    {
        MyVotes = new MyCollection<string>();
    }
}

public class MyCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public new void Add(T t)
    {
        base.Add(t);
        
        // how do I find out what property name this collection is within MyClass object?
    }
}
```

Comment: There is none. What if you call this on a variable? The caller shouldn't care what the values for its parameters are called. Why do you want to know?

Comment: This looks a bit ugly and very bad idea. What are you trying to achieve? There should be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: I'm trying to simplify a collection handler whereby when an entry appears it calls AutoMapper and dumps it into another list. I can get around this by provide more compile time types into the class, just thought there might be a simpler approach.

Comment: It's an ObservableCollection, right? So observe it. If you need MyClass to do something when an item is added to the collection, just have it handle the collection's CollectionChanged event. The collection itself should not need to know anything about where it is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have full control over the source, so I'd suggest just passing the information you need into the collection via a constructor parameter.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyCollection<string> MyVotes { get; }
    
    public MyClass()
    {
        MyVotes = new MyCollection<string>(nameof(MyVotes));
    }
}

public class MyCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private readonly string _propertyName;

    public MyCollection(string propertyName) => _propertyName = propertyName

    public new void Add(T t)
    {
        base.Add(t);
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Using {_propertyName}");
    }
}
```

I've used `nameof` here to make it refactoring safe. If you need to pass more than just the property name, e.g. the `PropertyInfo`, you could do that instead.